# how doesn't an exception occur when getting a zero-length substruing? C#

Tags: c#

```
string jgh = "n";
string fff = jgh.Substring(1, 0);
```

Can you please tell me how doesn't an exception occur when I create a substring from position 1 of jgh and set th length to 0? is there something in between the n and "?
I know this is useless but I am just curious.

Comment: Don't call it if you know the string is shorter than the index you want to look at.

Answer (score 1):

In description of the method u have explanation which states :

```
        "Exceptions:
        T:System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException:
        startIndex plus length indicates a position not within 
        this instance. -or- startIndex
        or length is less than zero."
```

In other words for exception to happen sum of your starting index and length needs to be greater than length of the string or index needs to be less than zero !!

Comment: Okay but how does it return an emty string if I am tellung it to return "nothing"?

Answer (score 0):

The [Microsoft reference](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,8281103e6f23cb5c):

```
   public String Substring(int startIndex, int length) {
                
    //Bounds Checking.
    if (startIndex < 0) {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("startIndex", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_StartIndex"));
    }

    if (startIndex > Length) {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("startIndex", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_StartIndexLargerThanLength"));
    }

    if (length < 0) {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("length", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_NegativeLength"));
    }

    if (startIndex > Length - length) {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("length", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_IndexLength"));
    }
    Contract.EndContractBlock();

    if( length == 0) {
        return String.Empty;
    }

    if( startIndex == 0 && length == this.Length) {
        return this;
    }

    return InternalSubString(startIndex, length);
}
```

So, `startIndex` must not be larger than `Length`, bit is allowed to be equal to `Length`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcuxCsIwFIXhuXmKS6cUNOhcnFxbEDo4iEOMN2mkTSA3FUT67DGhg@t3/qNor3zAlBayzsDwoYhzy9QkieASvAlyhi@rKMpoFby9fUIvreMUQz7c7iCDoaYk1UbwMiOcoHZ1@zetdba8iGF5bMaPOzg0pTl7R35CcQ02Ymcd8pyLDp2JYwlWtqb0Aw)

Comment: Okay but how does it return an emty string if I am tellung it to return "nothing"?
To be honest this neede to be my question.